# Problems with "includes" using Sequelize when a composite foreign key is used

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

Here is a sample of my main table:

```
+-------------+------------------------+--------------------+
| tenant      | vas_id                 | friendly_name      |
+-------------+------------------------+--------------------+
| brand_1     | 1gb_data_zone1         | 1GB Data in Zone 1 |
| brand_1     | promo_summer_2019_10GB | 10GB for Summer    |
| brand_1     | roaming_prepaid        | Roaming            |
| brand_1     | voicemail_prepaid      | Voicemail          |
| brand_2     | test_vas               | Test               |
| brand_2     | roaming_prepaid        | Roaming            |
| brand_2     | voicemail_prepaid      | Voicemail          |
+-------------+------------------------+--------------------+
```

`tenant` and `vas_id` are the two primary keys (a.k.a. composite primary keys) in this table, and they are used together as constain to another table, 1:N relationship:

```
+---------+------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| tenant  | vas_id                 | activation_cost | deactivation_cost | modification_cost |
+---------+------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| brand_1 | 1gb_data_zone1         |            2000 |                 0 |                 0 |
| brand_1 | promo_summer_2019_10GB |               0 |                 0 |                 0 |
| brand_1 | roaming_prepaid        |               0 |                 0 |                 0 |
| brand_1 | voicemail_prepaid      |               0 |                 0 |                 0 |
| brand_2 | test_vas               |               0 |                 0 |                 0 |
| brand_2 | roaming_prepaid        |               0 |                 0 |                 0 |
| brand_2 | voicemail_prepaid      |               0 |                 0 |                 0 |
+---------+------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------
```

**Would you say that this structure can get along with Sequelize?**

Here is the code that I use to mark the two primary keys:

```
const vas = serviceLayerDB.define('vas',
    { // Database columns:
        tenant: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(45),
            primaryKey: true
        },
        vas_id: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
            primaryKey: true
        }
        friendly_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100)
        }
    }

const vas_pricing = serviceLayerDB.define('vas_pricing',
    { // Database columns:
        tenant: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(45),
            primaryKey: true
        },
        vas_id: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
            primaryKey: true
        },
        activation_cost: {
            type: Sequelize.NUMBER
        },
        deactivation_cost: {
            type: Sequelize.NUMBER
        },
        modification_cost: {
            type: Sequelize.NUMBER
        }
    });
```

...and this is the code that I use to relate the table above with another table (vas_pricing):

```
vas.hasOne(vas_pricing, { foreignKey: 'vas_id' });
vas.hasOne(vas_pricing, { foreignKey: 'tenant' });
```

**Strange things happen, for example, while executing the following code that finds on the main table AND also in the child table:**

```
let options = {
    where: {
        tenant: 'brand_1',
        vas_id: 'promo_summer_2019_10GB'
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: vas_pricing,
            required: false
        }
    ]
};
vas.findAll(options)
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "tenant": "brand_1",
        "vas_id": "promo_summer_2019_10GB",
        "friendly_name": "10GB During Summer",
        "vas_pricing": {
            "tenant": "brand_1",
            "vas_id": "1gb_data_zone1",
            "activation_cost": 20,
            "deactivation_cost": 0,
            "modification_cost": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "tenant": "brand_1",
        "vas_id": "promo_summer_2019_10GB",
        "friendly_name": "10GB During Summer",
        "vas_pricing": {
            "tenant": "brand_1",
            "vas_id": "promo_summer_2019_10GB",
            "activation_cost": 0,
            "deactivation_cost": 0,
            "modification_cost": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "tenant": "brand_1",
        "vas_id": "promo_summer_2019_10GB",
        "friendly_name": "10GB During Summer",
        "vas_pricing": {
            "tenant": "brand_1",
            "vas_id": "roaming_prepaid",
            "activation_cost": 0,
            "deactivation_cost": 0,
            "modification_cost": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "tenant": "brand_1",
        "vas_id": "promo_summer_2019_10GB",
        "friendly_name": "10GB During Summer",
        "vas_pricing": {
            "tenant": "brand_1",
            "vas_id": "voicemail_prepaid",
            "activation_cost": 0,
            "deactivation_cost": 0,
            "modification_cost": 0
        }
    }
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
    {
        "tenant": "brand_1",
        "vas_id": "promo_summer_2019_10GB",
        "friendly_name": "10GB During Summer",
        "vas_pricing": {
            "tenant": "brand_1",
            "vas_id": "promo_summer_2019_10GB",
            "activation_cost": 0,
            "deactivation_cost": 0,
            "modification_cost": 0
        }
    }
]
```

I have been banging my head for days looking for a solution without success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of research, I have concluded that Sequelize will work problematically when using two foreign keys together and trying to find in a child model.

My workaround has been to keep the structure that I have in the database, and set the second key as unique and tell Sequelize that it is the only primary and foreign key, even though is not.

That way Sequelize works and I keep all the data consistency at the database level.

**Overview of the changes:**

`tenant` and `vas_id` are still primary keys and composite foreign keys to the `vas_pricing` table. But `vas_id` is now unique:

```
+-------------+------------------------+--------------------+
| tenant      | vas_id (unique)        | friendly_name      |
+-------------+------------------------+--------------------+
| brand_1     | 1gb_data_zone1         | 1GB Data in Zone 1 |
| brand_1     | promo_summer_2019_10GB | 10GB for Summer    |
| brand_1     | roaming_prepaid_b1     | Roaming            |
| brand_1     | voicemail_prepaid_b1   | Voicemail          |
| brand_2     | test_vas               | Test               |
| brand_2     | roaming_prepaid_b2     | Roaming            |
| brand_2     | voicemail_prepaid_b2   | Voicemail          |
+-------------+------------------------+--------------------+
```

In the `vas_pricing` table, everything stays as it was:

```
+---------+------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| tenant  | vas_id                 | activation_cost | deactivation_cost | modification_cost |
+---------+------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| brand_1 | 1gb_data_zone1         |            2000 |                 0 |                 0 |
| brand_1 | promo_summer_2019_10GB |               0 |                 0 |                 0 |
| brand_1 | roaming_prepaid        |               0 |                 0 |                 0 |
| brand_1 | voicemail_prepaid      |               0 |                 0 |                 0 |
| brand_2 | test_vas               |               0 |                 0 |                 0 |
| brand_2 | roaming_prepaid        |               0 |                 0 |                 0 |
| brand_2 | voicemail_prepaid      |               0 |                 0 |                 0 |
+---------+------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

I removed `tenant` as one of the primary keys:

```
const vas = serviceLayerDB.define('vas',
    { // Database columns:
        tenant: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(45),
            // primaryKey: true - NOT ANYMORE
        },
        vas_id: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
            primaryKey: true
        }
        friendly_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100)
        }
    }

const vas_pricing = serviceLayerDB.define('vas_pricing',
    { // Database columns:
        tenant: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(45),
            // primaryKey: true - NOT ANYMORE
        },
        vas_id: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
            primaryKey: true
        },
        activation_cost: {
            type: Sequelize.NUMBER
        },
        deactivation_cost: {
            type: Sequelize.NUMBER
        },
        modification_cost: {
            type: Sequelize.NUMBER
        }
    });
```

...and Sequelize now treats `vas_id` that as the only primary key:

```
vas.hasOne(vas_pricing, { foreignKey: 'vas_id' });
```

**Result:**

Sequelize now has no problems to find the proper child entries, and MySQL takes care of data consistency to prevent wrong data from being written in the wrong `tenant` and `vas_id` key pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you're more looking for the `vas_pricing` than the `vas`. So I'd recommend you make the query on `vas_pricing` instead:

```
let options = {
  where: {
    tenant: 'brand_1',
    vas_id: 'promo_summer_2019_10GB'
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: vas,
      required: false
    }
  ]
};

vas_pricing.findAll(options)
.then(function(data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: I have eddited your message by mistake. I was trying to edit my own. Please someone revert.

Comment: Hello. Is not what I am trying to achieve, but thank you very much for your suggestion. I have shared the final solution. It seems there is little that can be done due to Sequelize not supporting composite foreign keys.